# Dense locally convex subspace

Tags: locally-convex-spaces

$V$ is a locally convex space. I can't manage to prove that a subspace $M$ is necessarily dense if $\forall f\in V^*(f(M)=\lbrace{0\rbrace} \implies f(V)=\lbrace{0\rbrace})$.

All I have is $\exists x_0 \exists I \subset \mathbb{N} \text{   finite} \quad \exists \varepsilon > 0 \quad | (\cap_I B_i(x_0, \varepsilon))\cap M = \emptyset$ where $B_i$ stands for a "semi"-ball for seminorm $i$

The context is the analytic Hahn-Banach theorem, but I don't really see how that helps. I also have proved that for any $x\neq0$ there exists $g\in V^*$ such that $g(x)=1$, which I thought may be useful but not quite getting there.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll assume that  $V$ is over a field $\Bbb K$, where $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

> All I have is $\exists x_0 \exists I \subset \mathbb{N} \text{   finite} \quad \exists \varepsilon > 0 \quad | (\cap_I B_i(x_0, \varepsilon))\cap M = \emptyset$ where $B_i$ stands for a "semi"-ball for seminorm $i$

We can finish your proof as follows. Put $A=\cap_I B_i(x_0, \varepsilon)$. Since the set $A$ is non-empty, open and convex, the set $M$ is non-empty and convex, and the sets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, by [Hahn-Banach separation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem) there exist a continuous linear map $f : V \to\Bbb K$ and a number $t\in\Bbb R$ such that $\operatorname{Re}f(a) < t\le \operatorname{Re} f(b)$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in M$. Since $M$ is a subspace,  $f(M)=\Bbb K$ or $f(M)=\{0\}$. The first assumption contradicts to the inequality $t\le \operatorname{Re} f(b)$ for all $b\in M$. Thus $f(M)=\{0\}$, whereas $f(a)\ne 0$ for each point $a\in A$.